# How to fix "The destination is read-only" error on HDD partition

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8, read-only

How to fix `The destination is read-only` error on HDD partition with Windows 8.1 dual boot?

[image]
<sup>**Error while copying to ntfs partition**</sup>

[image]

Comment: Mount it read-write.

Comment: how can i do this

Comment: Start by posting a screenshot of Gparted.

Comment: what i can't understand this please explain

Comment: Open Gparted (install it if not yet there), then take a screenshot of your disk, upload it to a sharing website like imgur and put here the link.

Comment: Install gparted from the Software Center or by running `apt-get install gparted`. Then launch it and post a screenshot of it.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EEX0v.png

Comment: then what can i do?

Comment: please tell me what do now

Comment: I couldn't get the usb stick I wanted to use usable either. None of the suggestions worked, either the stick was reformatted and then the system would no longer mount it or the stick remained 'read only'. I found a solution. I formatted the stick to FAT32 in my Apple that runs OSX High Sierra. After that, my Linux machines can read and write to it. I find it weird that this is the only working solution. I am not a power user, I just use Linux to extend the life of my aging hardware. Jumping through loops like this to get a usb stick to act like a usb stick doesn't help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have the same issue and tried almost everything. Fortunately, found a solution to the problem from this thread : [Read-only partition, dual boot WIn10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917695/read-only-partition-dual-boot-win10?rq=1)

The Windows 10 update reseted it to the default fast startup which is a form of hibernation.

You need to disable this feature (again, probably) in Windows and then shutdown, not reboot. Once done properly you'll be able to access the data partition normally with read/write permissions.

How to disable hibernate on windows : https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-enable-or-disable-hibernate-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 68):

For me the solution was quite simple:

```
killall nautilus
```

First I tried with gpart and disk utilities to erase the partition but the problem still there, I saw answers about mount by hand or about win solutions but it doesn't make sense for me because my usb was created with an image of ubuntu with dd!. At the end, it seems to be a nautilus's bug. Just restart your PC or kill your nautilus and the problem will gone.

Comment: Does logging out and back in also work?

Comment: I certainly don't know but I suppose. But it's easier to open a terminal with  ctr-alt-t and you don't lose your opened windows.

Comment: Same works also for Thunar: killall Thunar

Comment: This worked for me for a mounted network volume. That's just bizarre. Thank you.

Comment: Also worked with Nemo for me on Mint 18.3.

Comment: @Rodrigo thanks worked for Ubuntu 16.04 as well

Answer (score 6):

Open the terminal (MAKE SURE THAT YOU DON'T HAVE ANYTHING OPEN THAT USES THAT DRIVE!) and then type:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw  /dev/sda3
```

Now you should have the drive mounted as read-write. If not, then try:

```
sudo mount -f -o remount,rw /dev/sda3
```

or
    sudo umount /dev/sda3
    sudo mount -rw /dev/sda3

If the umount was successful but the mount after it was failed try to put at the last mount command in this answer, in front or after the `-rw` argument `-f` to force the operation.

(NOTE: I HAVEN'T TRIED THIS BUT I'VE USED THESE COMMANDS AT MY OWN PROBLEMS LIKE THIS BUT ONLY SOME OF THEM ARE WORKING. FOR ME THIS WAS HAPPEN A WHILE AGO AND I CAN'T REMEMBER THE EXACT SAME COMMANDS THAT I USED TO FIX THE PROBLEM AND THERE CAN BE SOME SYNTAX ERRORS AT SOME COMMANDS AND I CAN MISSED SOME COMMANDS THAT CAN FIX YOUR PROBLEM.)

Comment: i'll try this but i can't do this

Comment: i think i can't understand that

Comment: Shortly: Open terminal and type :  sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda3 /mnt/8C7496A274968E98 then press enter.

Comment: i tryed but it not work

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdd1
```

replace `sdd1`  with your hdd or pendrive.

To check which one is yours type in terminal:

```
lsblk
```

and find your drive there and notice the device or partition and replace yours in above command.

this might work :)

**note: "replace partition not disk"**

Comment: The right command is lsblk not lsblck.