# Read-only partition, dual boot WIn10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, read-only

I am no longer able to write on the data partition files in Ubuntu, due to a "read-only" message appearing.

I have 3 partitions: one has Ubuntu installed (1), one is for Win10 (2)
 (dual boot) and the 3rd (3) is for data storage.
Today I updated Win10 and I am no longer able to access the data storage (3) partition from Ubuntu. Usually this error appears when I access Ubuntu while Win10 is not shut down but hibernated. Instead this time the error appears even if Win10 is shut down!
I don't get what's going on. Any clue?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The Windows 10 update reseted it to the default *fast startup* which is a form of hibernation.

You need to disable this feature (again, probably) in Windows and then shutdown, not reboot. Once done properly you'll be able to access the data partition normally with read/write permissions.

[image: The location of Fast Boot option in windows10]

Comment: I have changed that option from windows and now it works, thanks.

Comment: This happened to me in the last month. It's really very sucky that Windows changes the setting back. It cost me quite a bit of time.

Comment: I've had that setting off and it was still returning a Read Only message. The solution is the same as above, boot into Windows and perform a normal shutdown.

Comment: This option is disabled in my case, as I am using office laptop.

Comment: This has been bugging me for months now without any fix in site. This fixed it. Appreciate it.

Comment: I disabled fast startup, but I still have this same problem. If I shutdown my laptop (windows) and then I go on ubuntu, the partition is read-only, however if I restart it, it works normally. Basically it acts the same as if fast startup would be on, even if it is turned off. Any ideas what may be causing this?

Comment: I just spent hours pulling my hair out on a dual boot machine. This was the answer that so many other posts failed to resolve. Many thanks !!!

Answer (score 5):

Open the terminal and write the command

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

It will show your file system

identify the partition you want permission for read and write

then type the command and give the partition name like this to your specific sda

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda3
```

Comment: If Windows hibernated, it's not a good idea to enforce read/write for a shared partition. -1

Answer (score 3):

You may encounter this filesystem error while in dual boot.

Sometimes the feature "Disable Fastboot" is prohibited to change by non-admin user by group policy restriction.

The below solution will help for all situations.

Login to windows, close all opened windows if any and execute following, from Run dialog

```
`shutdown /f /r /t 0`
```

> /f  Force running applications to close without forewarning users.

> /r  Full shutdown and restart the computer.

> /t xxx  Set the time-out period before shutdown to xxx seconds, here /t 0 for immediate shutdown.

Comment: For some reason, it didn't work for me with /t0 attribute. But thanks anyway, as "disable fastboot" is prohibited for me too, this was my only way to get back to my data partition.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows is hibernated, refused to mount**

Chances are that Windows really is hibernated. Windows does this automatically when you tell it to shutdown normally. The benefit is that you get a faster apparent start-up time.

To shutdown Windows without hybernating, issue the following at a command-prompt (in Windows):

```
shutdown /s
```

You might also want `include /t 0` for immediate shutdown.

I found a nice tutorial to set up a launcher for this: How to Do a Full Shutdown in Windows 8 Without Disabling Hybrid Boot.

The simpler approach to actually shutting down Windows is to 'restart' (rather than 'shutdown'), but then intercept the boot process and boot Linux instead of letting it boot Windows.

**credit**:
[nobar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/6764/nobar)

Answer (score 0):

for me it was solution to restart from Linux go to windows, restart from windows and go bask to Linux. I guess windows did not close some permissions.

Comment: When you restart Windows from the login screen, the Windows won't suspend. That's why you were able to disable the fast boot by restarting the Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable Hibernation Windows 10/11

Press the Windows button on the keyboard to open Start menu or Start screen.
Search for cmd . In the search results list, right-click Command Prompt, and then select Run as Administrator.
When you are prompted by User Account Control, select Continue.
At the command prompt, type powercfg.exe /hibernate off, and then press Enter.
Type exit, and then press Enter to close the Command Prompt window.
Than disable the fast startup in the power options as well.