# Dual-boot: (Windows 11 Pro, Ubuntu Desktop 22.10) Can't see files from other OS in shared NTFS partition

Tags: dual-boot, shared-folders, disk-check

My laptop has dual boot windows 11 and Ubuntu. The problem is that I can not find files created with Ubuntu in Windows, while files created by Windows are visible in Ubuntu.

If after creating files in Ubuntu I boot to Windows and execute *check disk (Chkdsk)* in Windows, **sometimes** it says there are some errors in the partition, and by fixing them **some of** the created files are found! In this case, files that windows did not find will not be visible in Ubuntu anymore (It seems that by fixing, windows deleted them).

I searched a lot and tried almost all the things people suggested. Mostly it said that the problem is about the fast startup of windows (for example [(SOLVED) Dual-boot: (Windows 10, Ubuntu 18.04) Can't see files from other OS in shared NTFS partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141810/solved-dual-boot-windows-10-ubuntu-18-04-cant-see-files-from-other-os-in)). Although it is disabled my problem is not solved.

**OS:**

- Windows 11 Pro (22H2) OS Build: 22621.963
- Ubuntu Desktop 22.10

My laptop has two storage: one SSD drive and one HDD drive. I use SSD for installing OS and saving files. HDD is used for files. Each one has some partitions, generally as below:

- **SSD:** Windows, Ubuntu, Document (+ booting partitions such as EFI)
- **HDD:** one primary partition, two logical partitions

SSD partitioning is **GPT**, and HDD partitioning is **MBR**.

*fast startup* is disabled in windows. ([Read-only partition, dual boot WIn10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917695/read-only-partition-dual-boot-win10?rq=1))

Output of `sudo fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 116,69 MiB, 122359808 bytes, 238984 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 63,22 MiB, 66293760 bytes, 129480 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 63,23 MiB, 66301952 bytes, 129496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 72,86 MiB, 76398592 bytes, 149216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 72,91 MiB, 76451840 bytes, 149320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 238,88 MiB, 250482688 bytes, 489224 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 238,43 MiB, 250015744 bytes, 488312 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 931,51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 870 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 79DA08C5-2591-4E31-18C8-7DEAC4A26E6C

Device         Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048     206847     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda2     206848     239615      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     239616  481064959  480825344 229,3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  481064960  482580479    1515520   740M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5  482584576  549693439   67108864    32G unknown
/dev/sda6  549693440  569405439   19712000   9,4G Linux swap
/dev/sda7  569405440  904949759  335544320   160G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda8  904949760 1953521663 1048571904   500G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sdb: 931,51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000LM024 HN-M
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5435e47b

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1             2048  314791935  314789888 150,1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2        314793675 1953521663 1638727989 781,4G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb5        314793744 1153673740  838879997   400G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb6       1153675912 1953518593  799842682 381,4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/loop8: 346,33 MiB, 363151360 bytes, 709280 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 91,69 MiB, 96141312 bytes, 187776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 240 KiB, 245760 bytes, 480 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 144,96 MiB, 151998464 bytes, 296872 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 49,62 MiB, 52031488 bytes, 101624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop14: 304 KiB, 311296 bytes, 608 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop13: 304 KiB, 311296 bytes, 608 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop15: 362,99 MiB, 380624896 bytes, 743408 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop16: 369,48 MiB, 387424256 bytes, 756688 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop17: 26,3 MiB, 27574272 bytes, 53856 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop18: 26,3 MiB, 27574272 bytes, 53856 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```