# Read only Drive, Dual boot Windows 10. Kubuntu on 2nd internal HDD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, permissions, kubuntu, windows-10

I am sort of new on linux environment. So I had dual booted my laptop.

Now I can copy paste files on windows partitioned drives and the drives I had partitioned while installing the kubuntu. I did kept some free space, and partitioned that while in the OS. This new one was done in Kubuntu Partition Manager. And I am not getting any permission to create file/ folder, or even copy paste. 
.
.

Added Note, Already saw the post [Read-only partition, dual boot WIn10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917695/read-only-partition-dual-boot-win10), and it did not help. Would appreciate your help. Terminal is giving me `Refusing to operate on read-write mounted device /dev/sdb9.`

I came to know about this problem, when i was trying set a Steam Library in Kubuntu.
[image]

Comment: You haven't provided much specifics, however a RO/read-only file system means it was either mounted RO (not RW)  OR  logical errors were detected on the drive and it was flipped from RW to RO to stop errors getting worse and data loss.  You'll note that in messages on screen (if using terminal or in logs if using gui).  After `fsck` or file-system check & correction it'll stop flipping to RO.  You provided no detail that allows us to know what your actual issue is (could be permissions, or other causes too...)

Comment: "It did not help" does not give us much to work with. Complete output and error messages offer more and better clues to what might be going on.

Comment: the terminal is giving me "Refusing to operate on read-write mounted device /dev/sdb9."

Comment: @guiverc, I just had run 'fsck -n -f' . and this whole bunch of stuff came.

Comment: You shouldn't `fsck` a mounted drive.  The easiest way to `fsck` it to boot a 'live' system (such as Ubuntu install media using the "*Try Ubuntu*") so your hdd/ssd isn't in use, and `fsck` from there.   Please don't provide detail via command, edit your question and place detail there, but do **not** `fsck` a mounted fs, `umount` first (when it's not in use)

Comment: @Battleseeker_Rex can you open a terminal and give output of `mount` command? Want to confirm if /media/battleseeker_rex/Steam is mounted in read only mode.

Comment: Have any windows driver in windows to read/write the  linux filesystem?

Comment: @ignite I dotn know if the result gonna be same, since i fixed the problem,  by coming back to windows and instead of partitioning that empty space in linux. I did the partition now in Windows. 
It is working perfectly fine now. I will look into it.