# Destination is Read only error on ubuntu file system

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 17.04, read-only

I have dual boot ubuntu 17.04 along with Win 10.

*lsblk* command gave me this:

```
  sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
    ├─sda1   8:1    0  89.2G  0 part 
    ├─sda2   8:2    0 154.1G  0 part 
    ├─sda3   8:3    0 202.4G  0 part 
    ├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
    └─sda5   8:5    0    20G  0 part /
```

sda1,sda2,sda3 become read only, and I cant write anything to it.
 I've tried [How to fix "The destination is read-only" error on HDD pratishthan](https://askubuntu.com/questions/809237/how-to-fix-the-destination-is-read-only-error-on-hdd-pratishthan) 
But none of the answers worked for me.
Please Help.

Comment: boot a live CD and run fsck on the drive - https://www.maketecheasier.com/check-repair-filesystem-fsck-linux/ Post the command you ran and any errors if you have problems.

Comment: Fortunately, the problem is solved using this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/917695/read-only-partition-dual-boot-win10?rq=1 
Thanks to @user685242 
Also thnx bodhi.zazen for the quick feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and write the command

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

It will show your file system

identify the partition you want permission for read and write

then type the command and give the partition name like this

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda3
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible fixes is the following:
On Windows, you have to turn off the fast startup option (here's how to do it: https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1045548).
Then shut down your system (shutdown, not restart!).
You should be then able to edit the Windows partition from Ubuntu.

NB: the fast startup option is reenabled by Windows after some updates. You will then have to do it again.