# How to add/delete/modify folders/files in storage media in Ubuntu when they are locked?

Tags: dual-boot

I am new to Linux
I have Ubuntu 17.04 dual booted along with windows 10.

I am unable to create new folder, file , paste a folder/file to the D drive (Found in other locations in Linux Ubuntu).

However I am able to view and read the data present in my D drive(of windows) in Ubuntu but unable to make changes.

Is there any way to make changes like adding a folder or file to the drive?

Thanks.

Comment: Boot Windows, disable *fast startup* ans shutdown (rebooting only may override the changes). Problem solved.

Comment: Which file format is your drive d? am sure its NTFS, if so you cannnot write because its mounted as read only filesystem

Comment: @savior123 doesn't have to do anything with NTFS though. Linux should be able to write to it. But when Windows isn't shutdown correctly it holds a lock on the drive anyway in this case he also wouldn't be able to read. Please add the output of `ls -l /media/` to your post. My first guess would be probably you mounted the drive with sudo permissions and now cannot write to it with normal user permissions.

Comment: @derHugo I could access the files after restarting back then(problem solved). Used Ubuntu over an year now. I got the same problem again and now even if i restart, i am unable to edit or delete or add files to the drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions: Any one of the three will solve the problem, try in the order as shown:

1. Check if windows is Shut down properly. Just start windows and shut it down.
2. [Just unmount and remount the file system with root user permissions as shown here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47538/how-to-make-read-only-file-system-writable)
3. [Disable fast startup from windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/809237/how-to-fix-the-destination-is-read-only-error-on-hdd-partition)

Answer (score 2):

**NB.** This is not necessarily the solution, but it is a practice that helps prevent your problem.

As noted by @Hemal, Windows did not shut down properly, technically. To ensure that Windows shuts down properly, you need to shut it down the **proper way**.

i.e.

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
2. Navigate to shutdown using directional arrows
3. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This procedure completely shuts down your windows and releases all drives of the machine.