# Cannot copy owned file

Tags: mount, copy

I have ownership access to files, but still paste option is disabled. I tried to change it with sudo, and got another error: `no such file or directory`

`chmod` throws `Read-only file system` error.

[image]

Also , I have mounted this drive as root, again `no such file or directory` was error was there.

Comment: What is the output of `mount | grep /media` and `ls -l <device name>/WinRadius.rar`?

Comment: Possibly related:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/809237/how-to-fix-the-destination-is-read-only-error-on-hdd-partition

Answer (score 1):

When you remount the filesystem you have to make sure that you mount it as Read-Write.

`sudo mount -o rw [Partition] [Target directory]`

for example:

`sudo mount -o rw /dev/sdb2 /mnt/data`